# master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/somedoamin.git

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, heroku

I am currently working on Angular 2 app and uploading it on heroku.
When i simply upload without using any calling any class in div . it uploads on heroku when i use `git push heroku master` 
like my appcomponent.html

```
<h1>
{{title}} 
</h1>
 <div>
<h2>Gtting started.....</h2>
</div>
```

till now it works fine. but as soon as i added these dives or any other div with styling

```
    `<div class="footer-newsletter">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <p style="color:#36b4d2">Search and Save</p>
                        <form>
                            <input type="search" name=query [(ngModel)]="query" 
                      #quer="ngModel"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" required>
                            <button type="button" (click)="Search()" class="btn btn-custom">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!-- End .container-fluid -->
                </div><!-- End .footer-newsletter -->
`
```

it gives me this error on heroku push master command

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/some.git'
```

i have added css files in assets and that works fine localy. can anyone please tell me what the reason behind this. i have wasted two days on it. any help will be highly appriciated.

**Package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "erecommender",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.2",
    "npm": "4.5.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```